# AttributeError at /circular/1/detail/ 'CircularDetail' object has no attribute 'pk' in Django

Tags: python, django

```
class CircularDetail(DeleteView):
    model = Circular
    template_name = 'genre/circular_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CircularDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['c'] = Circular.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        ctx['sittings'] = Sitting.objects.all()
        ctx['ballot'] = Sitting.objects.all()
        return ctx
```

Above view give me following errors:

**Traceback:**

```
File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  118.         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/myapp/genre/views.py" in get_context_data
  126.         ctx['c'] = Circular.objects.get(pk=self.pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /circular/1/detail/
Exception Value: 'CircularDetail' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I need your assistance to fix this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL parameters are passed via kwargs, so you can access it this way

```
self.kwargs.get("pk")
```

so change

```
ctx['c'] = Circular.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
```

to

```
ctx['c'] = Circular.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
```

Comment: It works, Thanks. Could you tell me how I could save one field value from one model to another model field value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix your base class to `DetailView` (instead of `DeleteView`)

`DetailView` inherited from `django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) which expects primary key to be in `slug` parameter, so fix your URL regexp to

```
r'^circular/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/detail$'
```

and access your object using `self.object` in view or just `{{ object }}` in template.